# gsub: Keep a given character only if between two digits/letters

Tags: r, gsub

I have a list of addresses that I would like to split into two arrays:

1. Address line (keeping special characters such as "-" whenever between two letters - c.f. `text.2`)
2. House number (keeping special characters such as "-" whenever between two digits)

Here is an example:

```
text.1 <- "CALLE COMPOSITOR LEHMBERG RUIZ 19-21"
text.2 <- "CALLE COMPOSITOR LEHMBERG-RUIZ 19-21"
```

To extract the house numbers, I tried using `gsub("[^0-9\\-]", "", x)` which works fine for `text.1` but not as well as desired for `text.2`:

```
> gsub("[^0-9\\-]", "", text.1)
[1] "19-21"
> gsub("[^0-9\\-]", "", text.2)
[1] "-19-21"
```

To extract the address line I used `gsub("[0-9]", "", x)` yielding a similar problem.

I could circumvent this issue with the following code:

```
ifelse( substr( gsub("[^0-9\\-]", "", x ), 1, 1 ) == "-" , 
        substr( gsub("[^0-9\\-]", "", x), 2, nchar( gsub("[^0-9\\-]", "", x) ) 
           )
        , gsub("[^0-9\\-]", "", x)
      )
```

yielding `"19-21"` for both `x = text.1` and `x = text.2`. However, as one can tell it is not very elegant.

My question would be if there is an "elegant" way to solve this issue (e.g. using `gsub` in a cleverer fashion)?

Comment: I would suggest using something like [stringr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf), it has much better text manipulation. If you have a guarantee that the number is at the end of the string, just split on whitespace and take the last element.

Comment: you can use `sub` (you don't need `gsub`) with sub-patterns within parenthesis, that you can address within the call `sub("(^.*)(\\s[0-9].*$)", "\\1", text.2)` or `trimws(sub("(^.*)(\\s[0-9].*$)", "\\2", text.2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a regular expression to `SKIP` when the pattern is true and remove all other characters

```
gsub("(\\d+)-(\\d+)(*SKIP)(*F)|.", "", text.1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "19-21"
gsub("(\\d+)-(\\d+)(*SKIP)(*F)|.", "", text.2, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "19-21"
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent to keep letters?

Comment: @nate.edwinton  What would be the expected output.  If you need `G-R`, then `gsub("([A-Z])-([A-Z])(*SKIP)(*F)|.", "", text.2, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: That would be expected `"CALLE COMPOSITOR LEHMBERG-RUIZ"`

Comment: @nate.edwinton  That would be `gsub("\\s*\\d+-\\d+", "", text.2)`

Answer (score 2):

I would advise to use str_extract instead of gsub in your case. You could d as follow:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(text.1,"[0-9]{1,3}\\-[0-9]{1,3}")
[1] "19-21"
str_extract(text.2,"[0-9]{1,3}\\-[0-9]{1,3}")
[1] "19-21"

str_extract(text.1,"[^0-9][A-Z\\-\\s]+")
[1] "CALLE COMPOSITOR LEHMBERG RUIZ "
str_extract(text.2,"[^0-9][A-Z\\-\\s]+")
[1] "CALLE COMPOSITOR LEHMBERG-RUIZ "
```